# Replace comma-separated element positions inside Python text

Tags: python, string, random, split

I'm trying to find a comma-separated value inside the text and change the position randomly. For example

```
 Good morning. I am James. The weather is very nice today. I ate apples, bananas, milk, sandwich this morning. 

And my favorite things are movies, music, read books. And my total assets are $1,555,555,`555.
```

In the above string, search for /apple, banana, milk, sandwich / movie, music, reading/ and change the location at random. Exclude the number ($1,555,555,555) here. So finally

```
Good morning. I am James. The weather is very nice today. I ate bananas, apples, sandwiches, milk this morning.

And my favorite things are music, movies, read books. And my total assets are $1,555,555,555.
```

I want to change it like this. The elements should change randomly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner, so I don't know what to do. I searched but it didn't come up with anything similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first extract the comma-separated values, split, and then use `random.shuffle`:

```
import random, re
s = """
Good morning. I am James. The weather is very nice today. I ate apples, bananas, milk, sandwich this morning. 

And my favorite things are movies, music, read books. And my total assets are $1,555,555,555.
"""
vals, base, r = re.findall('(?:[\$\w]+,\s*\w+)+(?:,\s*\w+)*|\w+,', s), re.sub('(?:[\$\w]+,\s*\w+)+(?:,\s*\w+)*|\w+,', '{}', s), []
for val in vals:
   if not val.startswith('$') and len(re.split(',\s*', val)) > 2:
      new_vals = re.split(',\s*', val)
      random.shuffle(new_vals)
      r.append(', '.join(new_vals))
   else:
      r.append(val)

new_string = base.format(*r)
```

Output:

```
Good morning. I am James. The weather is very nice today. I ate bananas, apples, sandwich, milk this morning. 

And my favorite things are music, movies, read books. And my total assets are $1,555,555,555.
```

Comment: thank you. Very good. However, is it possible to make it work only when there are three or more elements separated by commas (ex element 1, element 2, element 3)? If it works when there are two, the sentence will be transformed and the sentence will be awkward even if there is only one comma in the sentence.

Comment: @anfwkdrn Can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: """abc1, abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abc2, abc2, abc2 abcdefgh abcdefgh abc3, abc3, abc3, abc3 abcdef """

It means that it does not work when there is one comma like abc1, and it works only when there are two or more commas like abc2 and abc3.

Comment: Sorry, I think the transmission of meaning is wrong. If there is one comma like abc1, leave it as it is. It is corrected only when there are two or more commas like abc2 and abc3.

Comment: @anfwkdrn Glad to help!

Comment: @anfwkdrn If you would like to further test the extent of regexes, I'd recommend seeing  [regex101](https://regex101.com/).